# Run shell commands with Python subprocess

Tags: python, compilation, subprocess

i encountered a problem.
I want to run a command: `leaks -atExit -- ./a.out < test.in | grep LEAK` in subprocess in Python. But instead of input beeing passed with `< test.in`, I want to take it from variable.
Please help.

In the different part of my code, I tried:

```
res = subprocess.run(['./a.out'], capture_output=True, text=True, input=self.input_text, check=True)
```

and it worked perfecly. But when I want to do it simmilarly,

```
res = subprocess.run(['leaks', '-atExit', '--', './a.out', '|', 'grep',' LEAK'], capture_output=True, text=True, input=self.input_text, check=True)
```

It does not work.

Comment: You'll need `shell=True` to get your pipe (`|`) and redirection processed at least. And probably also the full path to `leaks`.

Comment: Ok, I managed to resolve my problem.

command = 'leaks -atExit -- ./a.out <' + str(self.input_filepath) + '| grep LEAK'

res = subprocess.run(command, text=True, capture_output=True, shell=True)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve my problem.

```
command = 'leaks -atExit -- ./a.out <' + str(self.input_filepath) + '| grep LEAK'
   res = subprocess.run(command, text=True, capture_output=True, shell=True)
```

Worked